# Door Monitoring Through OBD-II Bus

Tags: electrical, ford, obd-ii, locks, door

I have a Ford Fiesta Style (05) and was wondering if it would be possible to determine the status of the doors of the vehicle through the OBD-II bus?
In particular I want to know whether or not the doors are locked or unlocked - is this something that can be attained through OBDII?

Comment: you'd need to be able to access the body control module and figure out which pid belongs to the various doors.

Comment: You could just do a trial and error. Check what happens when you open a door, and check what happens when you open a different door. If the same things change, then it's not possible.